# Struts2: Ajax response not received sent by Result in jQuery

Tags: jquery, struts2

I send an Ajax request to an `Action` class and try to get the response from a `Result`.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('#button').click(function(){                    
            $.get('ajax.action','query="hi server:)")',function(x,r,s){                    
            alert("server said :"+r+"-stat-"+s.status);                    
            })
```

Here always the response is 'success' which not the expected response.
Here is my Action class's execute().

```
String response;
String query;
     @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        response=query+" - Struts added :";        

        setResponse(response);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

There a getters and setter for string response and query have been written(not showed here).
Here is my `Result` class

```
public class AjaxResponse implements Result {

@Override
public void execute(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("I am the Ajax Rsponse RESULT");// this is displayed in the console
     PrintWriter out =
                ServletActionContext.getResponse().getWriter();
    try {
        ServletActionContext.getResponse().setContentType("text/plain");

        ValueStack valueStack = ai.getStack();
       // Object resObj= valueStack.findValue("response");
        out.print("hi I am server ...");

        System.out.println("Response WROTE---");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }finally{

    out.close();
        System.out.println("Response Close "); // this is displayed in the console
    }        
}
```

}

Here is how I added my Result class to struts.xml

```
 <result-types>        
        <result-type name="ajaxResponse" class="com.app.ajax.AjaxResponse" />  
 </result-types>
```

Here is how I declared the action

```
<action name="ajax" class="com.app.action.AjaxSupport">
        <result type="ajaxResponse"/>
    </action>
```

The alert always gives only *SUCCESS* , not the expected result 'hi I am server ...' .
The console displays the Result class's prints-("I am the Ajax Response RESULT","Response WROTE---","Response Close") I used a separate Result class for loose couple the task and do the business logic inside the action class.
Please any one let me know where my problem is ?

Comment: IMO the biggest problem is that you're duplicating work that's already been done for you. Also not sure why you set `response` directly then use the setter to set it to itself.

Comment: go with JSON and Jquery..the best and elegant solution

Comment: @Dave Newton. Thank you. It s my fault not to declare the type of 'response' and 'query'. Both are type of `String`. 'response' means a simple text to be sent as the response. Any way I m not clear that "you're duplicating work that's already been done for you" . Would you explain more please? then how my class should be then ?

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi. Thanks. I m still new for Struts. I want to send a simple request and get a response in between browser and the application. First I try to go for a simple task. Then later I ll be able to do much more as you suggest.

Comment: have you tried stream result to see how this will work for you? may be this will help you a bit [http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/ajax.html]

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi. Thanks for the link. I tried it. Not worked as that doc says.

Comment: hmm.But it didn't work for me. :(  I just copied and pasted and set as the project as it says too. There something wrong I can't find. Thanks Mr. Dave

Comment: YES, It works. I have mistaken one thing. Problem is in jQuery where the callback function. Returning success is right. callback method takes 3 paras. in order, response(which server sends) ,status, xhrObject. Here I have tested the status(which should be 'success'). I had to check  response,in my code 'x' not S. Extremely sorry for my mistake. Thank you All.

Comment: @AashMaharoon - Since there are no answers on this question, consider adding what worked for you as an answer to the question below. This will help others quickly find what solves the problem. The goal of SO is to be a resource not only for you, but for the thousands of people who will visit this page for years to come. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in not in Struts but where I check the result whether it s right or wrong.

```
$.get('ajax.action', 'query="hi server")', function(x, r, s) {                    
    alert("server said: " + r + "-stat-" + s.status);
```

According to this alert, the output is:

```
server said: success-stat-200
```

Problem was seeing this *success* . confused with callback function's parameters.

Here `'r'` is status of the response (I'd thought the response), s is `xmlHttpRequest` object.

I had to check not `r`, but `x` which is real expected value. Printing x's value, the real value of what the server sent appeared.

Comment: +1 for following up. Consider naming your parameters something easier to understand without having to look it up! :)